# Pytorch's GRUCell and inputs of higher dimension

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

[The documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRUCell.html) for Pytorch's GRUCell claims that in `torch.nn.GRUCell(input_size, hidden_size, bias=True)`, input_size is the number of expected features in the input. So it should be an int and you can think about the input as `(batch_size, input_size)`. I am building a model that its input is in the form `(batch_size, seq_len, input_size)` i.e. a batch of time series of length `seq_len` where at each given time we have an `input_size` dimensional vector. Is it possible to implement something like this using GRUCell? (natively changing the input_size to a tuple gives types error.)

Comment: Take a look at the example at the bottom of the documentation. They define a GRU with (input_size, hidden_size), and then the input is `torch.randn(6, 3, 10)` -> the input has dimensions corresponding to (batch_size, seq_len, input_size)! So seq_len doesn't need to be inserted as a parameter into nn.GRUCell. You can use it for what you what with no change.

Comment: If you feed `torch.randn(6, 3, 10)` into a GRUCell it will give an error. In the example you are mentioning they are turning the 3 dimensional tensor to 6 two dimensional ones and then they feed it, which looks very unnatural and also 6 is not the batch_size but 3 is the batch_size and it becomes even more confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the batch_size and seq_len. If you want a GRU cell such that `output = gru(input)` and `input` has 3 dimensions, I don't think there is a native way to do it in PyTorch. The native way is to use a loop (see also [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) ). You can always write one (a module inheriting nn.Module that will implement this loop). I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.